# Funcion en Javascript - Array

Tags: javascript, array, funciones

Me pidieron en mi clase escribir una función que muestre la tabla de multiplicar del 6 (del 0 al 60). a demás tengo que tener en cuenta que la función devuelve un array con los resultados de la tabla de multiplicar del 6 en orden creciente.

Tengo esto hasta el momento:

```
function tablaDelSeis(){
  let arrayTablaDelSeis = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++){
    arrayTablaDelSeis.push (6 * i);
  }
  return arrayTablaDelSeis;
}
```

¿Qué me faltaría para que funcione? o ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tenes que retornar valores del 0 a 60, tenes que inicializar la i en 0:

```
function tablaDelSeis(){
      let arrayTablaDelSeis = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        arrayTablaDelSeis.push (6 * i);
      }
      return arrayTablaDelSeis;
}

tablaDelSeis();
```

Comment: plop....gracias!